# tengo un problema al enviar datos por el socket

Tags: java, android-studio, socket, tcpip

Estoy creando una aplicación en la que puedo conectarme a un robot mesero a través del protocolo TCP/IP - ssocket. Mi socket se inicializa "correctamente", pero cuando quiero enviar un mensaje al robot (servidor), mi aplicación falla. Básicamente envío el mensaje desde un Fragmento (AudioFragment) en otra actividad diferente a la Actividad Principal

Aqui esta mi codigo

PD: Perdon si la MainActivity se ve algo caotica, tambien tuve problemas en ella al intentar inicializar el socket desde el hilo principal, afortunadamente eso ya esta arreglado

Main Activity: Donde inicializo el socket y envio el intent que abre la activity donde esta el fragment desde el cual envio el mensaje

```
    package com.example.aoborobot;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.aoborobot.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "Main_Activity";
    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<DeviceCard> recyclerViewDatabase;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    DeviceCardAdapter adapter;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    ImageView closeDialogButton;
    Button addDeviceButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_1);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add_device_fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showAddDialog();
            }
        });
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerViewDatabase = new ArrayList<>();
        setRecyclerAdapter();
    }



    public void setRecyclerAdapter() {
        if (adapter == null){
            adapter = new DeviceCardAdapter(recyclerViewDatabase,
                    this,
                    this::openActivity,
                    this::deleteRecyclerViewItem);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            System.out.println("Creando el adapter");
        }else {
            adapter.setItems(recyclerViewDatabase);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            System.out.println("Notificando cambios al adapter");
        }

    }
    private void showAddDialog(){
        View alertCustomDialog = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_add_device,null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setView(alertCustomDialog);
        closeDialogButton = (ImageView) alertCustomDialog.findViewById(R.id.add_dialog_close);
        addDeviceButton = (Button) alertCustomDialog.findViewById(R.id.add_device_button);

        final AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();

        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.show();

        closeDialogButton.setOnClickListener(view -> dialog.cancel());
        addDeviceButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            EditText IPEditText = (EditText) alertCustomDialog.findViewById(R.id.ip_edit_text);
            EditText portEditText = (EditText) alertCustomDialog.findViewById(R.id.port_edit_text);
            EditText nameEditText = (EditText) alertCustomDialog.findViewById(R.id.name_edit_text);
            executeAddDeviceTask(IPEditText.getText().toString().trim(),Integer.parseInt(portEditText.getText().toString().trim()),nameEditText.getText().toString().trim(),dialog, MainActivity.this);
        });

    }

    public ArrayList<DeviceCard> getRecyclerViewDatabase() {
        return recyclerViewDatabase;
    }

    private void executeAddDeviceTask (String ip, int port, String name, AlertDialog dialog, Context context){
        new AsyncAddDeviceTask().execute(ip,port,name,dialog,context);
    }
    public void deleteRecyclerViewItem(DeviceCard item){
        recyclerViewDatabase.remove(item);
        setRecyclerAdapter();
    }
    public void openActivity(SocketClient socketClient) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RobotActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("deviceSocket",socketClient);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
class AsyncAddDeviceTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {
    private static final String TAG = "Async_add";
    String ip,name;
    int port;
    AlertDialog dialog;
    MainActivity context;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        this.ip = (String)objects[0];
        this.port = (int) objects[1];
        this.name = (String) objects[2];
        this.dialog = (AlertDialog) objects[3];
        this.context = (MainActivity) objects[4];

        int statusInit;
        SocketClient socketClient = new SocketClient(ip,port);
        //SocketClient socketClient = new SocketClient(IPEditText.getText().toString().trim(),Integer.parseInt(portEditText.getText().toString().trim()));
        statusInit = socketClient.init();
        if(statusInit == 0){
            Log.w(TAG, "No inicie el socket antes de instanciarlo");
            dialog.cancel();

        } else if (statusInit == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"No se ha encontrado el dispositivo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Send toast that IP doesn't exists
            dialog.cancel();
        } else if (statusInit == 1) {
            DeviceCard deviceCard = new DeviceCard(socketClient,"#080940", name, DeviceCard.STATUS_CONNECTED);
            //DeviceCard deviceCard = new DeviceCard(socketClient,"#080940", nameEditText.getText().toString(), DeviceCard.STATUS_CONNECTED);
            context.getRecyclerViewDatabase().add(deviceCard);
            Log.d(TAG, socketClient.getMessage());
            dialog.dismiss();
            context.runOnUiThread(() -> context.setRecyclerAdapter());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

SocketClient: Clase para el socket, aqui lo inicializo, envio mensajes y recivo mensajes al y desde el servidor. Importante - el problema esta en la línea "output.writeUTF(message)" pero no se porque me da este error

```
package com.example.aoborobot;

import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class SocketClient implements Serializable {
    public final static String TAG = "Socket_Client";
    protected String serverIP;
    private final int serverPort;
    protected static String client_IP ;
    private transient Socket socket;
    private transient DataOutputStream output;
    private transient DataInputStream input;
    private String message;
    private ServerHandler handler;
    private onMessageReceived messageListener;

    public interface onMessageReceived {
        void onMessage(String messageReceived);
    }
    public  SocketClient (String serverIP, int serverPort){
        this.serverIP = serverIP;
        this.serverPort = serverPort;
    }

    public int init(){
        if (serverIP != null) {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "IP:" + serverIP);
                Log.d(TAG, "Port:" + serverPort);
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, serverPort);
                output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                Log.d(TAG, "socket creado");
                String messageReceived = input.readUTF();
                Log.d(TAG, "Mensaje de respuesta recibido: " + messageReceived);
                handler = new ServerHandler(this);

                if (messageReceived != null) {
                    message = messageReceived;
                    handler.start();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Iniciación del socket completa y handler iniciado");
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG,"El puerto no se pudo definir");
                return -1;
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e ){
                Log.d(TAG, "SocketTimeoutException al iniciar el Socket");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return -1;
            } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "IOException al iniciar el Socket");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public int send(String message) {
        int sendState = 1;
        try {
            output.writeUTF(message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            sendState= -1;
        }
        return sendState;
    }

    public ServerHandler getHandler() {return handler;}

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
        messageListener.onMessage(this.message);

    }

    public onMessageReceived getMessageListener() {
        return messageListener;
    }

    public void setMessageListener(onMessageReceived messageListener) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MessageListener setted");
        this.messageListener = messageListener;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setSocket(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

    public DataInputStream getInput() {return input;}

    public DataOutputStream getOutput() {return output;}

    public int getServerPort() {
        return serverPort;
    }

    public String getServerIP() {
        return serverIP;
    }

    public static String getClient_IP() {
        return client_IP;
    }
}
class ServerHandler extends Thread implements Serializable{
    private static final String TAG = "Server_Handler";
    private final SocketClient client;
    private final transient DataInputStream dis;
    private final transient DataOutputStream dos;

    ServerHandler (@NonNull SocketClient client){
        this.client = client;
        this.dis = client.getInput();
        this.dos = client.getOutput();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if(client.getMessageListener() != null) {
                try {
                    String message = dis.readUTF();
                    Log.d(TAG, "nueo mensaje del puerto: " + message);
                    client.setMessage(message);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AudioFragment: Aqui tengo un EditText y un botón que envía la órden a la instancia de socketCLient de que envie el mensaje especificado

```
package com.example.aoborobot;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AudioFragment extends Fragment implements SocketClient.onMessageReceived {
    private static final String TAG = "Audio_Fragment";
    Button sendButton;
    EditText messageEditText;
    TextView messageText;
    SocketClient socketClient;

    public AudioFragment (SocketClient socketClient) {
        this.socketClient = socketClient;
    }

    public AudioFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_audio, container, false);
        messageEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.message_edittext);
        messageText = view.findViewById(R.id.message_txt);
        sendButton = view.findViewById(R.id.send_message_btn);
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String messageToSend = messageEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                if (! messageToSend.equals("")){
                    int sendState = socketClient.send(messageToSend);
                    if (sendState == -1) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hubo un fallo al enviar el mensaje",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (sendState == 1){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"El mensaje se envió exitosamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String messageReceived) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Nuevo mesnaje desde el socket al fragment: " + messageReceived);
        messageText.setText(messageReceived);
    }
}
```

El error en mi terminal

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aoborobot, PID: 31646
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.aoborobot.SocketClient.send(SocketClient.java:82)
        at com.example.aoborobot.AudioFragment$1.onClick(AudioFragment.java:44)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Veo que output se inicializa en el método init(), pero no veo que llames a ese método en ningún sitio. Por tanto es normal que output sea null (que es lo que dice el error)

Comment: Si lo llamo, esta en la AsynTask del MainActivity en el método "doInBackground"

Comment: Entonces es posible que tengas una condición de carrera